# How do i run a method on an MVC application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

What i want to do:

I want to run a method on an MVC application in this way:

```
public static void test()
    {
        ModelVariables hey = new ModelVariables();

        hey.test = "hello world";
    }
```

Here i am basicallly storing "hello world" onto a global variable, simple right?

```
 public class ModelVariables
{

    public string test { get; set; }
}
```

now my public string 'test' has string "hello world", so far so good right?

then i want to verify that this worked by printing it in my html form:

```
@{


ModelVariables testee = new ModelVariables();
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

 @using (Html.BeginForm())
{
 <div>@testee.test</div>

}
```

@testee.test = "hello world", or so it seems... when i run the application, nothing shows up! wtf is going on and how do i fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass a value to the view in MVC you should put it in the ViewModel.

if you put this value in the ViewModel, the flow should look something like this:

**ViewModel / Model:**

```
public class TestViewModel
{
   public string testee { get; set; }
}
```

**View:**

```
@model testproject.Models.ViewModels.TestViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>@Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.testee)</div>
}
```

**FooController:**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new TestViewModel();
    model.testee = "hello world!";

    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: you understood the question and provided a copy/paste answer with good presentation and form, you sir are awesome

Answer (score 0):

No those are not global variable. `ModelVariables hey` and `ModelVariables testee` are two different instances and thus nothing shows up. You want to populate the data before showing it up

```
@{
ModelVariables testee = new ModelVariables()
{
  test = "Hello World!!!"
};
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where did you initialize the value of @testee.test? you never called the static method test() to initialze the variable.

```
@{

ModelVariables testee = new ModelVariables(){test = "Hello World"}; 
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

 @using (Html.BeginForm())
{
 <div>@testee.test</div>

}
```

This should work but as a good practice you should always declare you variables in your action method and make available in the view by using the ViewBag